# Searching through multilingual records using ElasticaBundle & Translatable

Tags: symfony, translation, elasticsearch, multilingual

I've created a multi-lingual website with Symfony2 using the (Gedmo) Translatable behavior extension for Doctrine2. This works fine but now i'm looking for a way to use the ElasticaBundle to create a nice searchoption. I want German users to search in the German-translation but also in the English translation.

At the moment i'm trying to use separate indexes for each language. My config.yml looks like this:

```
foq_elastica:    
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }    
    indexes:                
        articles_en:
            client:default                                                                                  
            types:
                article:
                mappings:
                    name: { boost: 5, analyzer: my_analyzer }                                                                         
                persistence:
                    driver: orm
                    model:  Test\SiteBundle\Entity\Article
                    identifier: id
                    provider:
                        service: elastica.translation.provider.article.en                        
                    finder:
        articles_de:
        ....
        articles_nl:
        .....
```

This works fine if you want to search through one index but searching two indexes seems not possible with this bundle or am I wrong?

Is there a way to do this? Any help will be appreciated!

Rick

Answer (score 3):

You should probably just add one index for every article in every language and add a language to your index. You can then search your index for articles in one or more languages.

Comment: Thnx, i'll try this. Your full answer can be found athttps://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle/issues/227#issuecomment-13282681

Comment: But then you can't use different analyzers for each language, am I right? Alas, the issue url is actually https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/227#issuecomment-13282681